# Running strapi project on hosting service provider

Tags: javascript, deployment, content-management-system, strapi

I don't understand how to run my Strapi project once it's online on the server. I have a website [vpftravel.com](http://vpftravel.com) and I want to fetch data from the Strapi collections (api) I created but the only way that Strapi runs is when I use the "start" command. I've read many times their deployment documentation but no luck. I also don't understand how I can access the Strapi dashboard once I've uploaded it to the hosting service's server.

Background on my project, it's just a regular JS, PHP and HTML site hosted on Aruba (hosting service). I've been using [DatoCMS](http://datocms.com) but I've surpassed the 10GB bandiwdth on their free tier hence why I'm looking into a locally hosted database.

Maybe Strapi is not the right tool for what I wanna do.

I'd appreciate any help.

This photo shows my personal project directory and I highlighted where the Strapi project is located inside the directory.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strapi is not a "flat file" type of web app, it's adminUI is but the backend needs to run as a service. This is something you would use PM2 for (and I would not recommend using IIS)

Comment: Excuse me for my ignorance, what's an IIS? What would you recommend me to use? Thanks.

Comment: IIS is Windows "Web server". The confusion here is that you are used to things like static html, php, ect and that is not what Strapi is. Think of say Apache, that is also a web server, Strapi in this case is acting like the web server. 

Strapi itself is an application that as to "run" on the system and is not a bunch of files that something else "runs".

If you edit a text document you are using something like Microsoft word or notepad, in this case Strapi is both the text file AND notepad. You would need to run node as a service using something like PM2 or a process manger for node